# Queuemetrics on centos 5

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, centos5

i'm trying to install **queuemetrics** on **centos 5** but keep getting this error message on my browser :-

```
"Error JDBC:When opening jdbc:mysql://localhost/queuemetrics?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''&autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&user=queuemetrics&password=javadude got error:
-- Inner Exception --
- Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - Error: - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - Stack trace: - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1328)
- at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1175)
- at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) - at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188) - at it.loway.tpf.SQL.openConnection(SQL.java:55) - at it.loway.tpf.transaction.servlets.LowayTransactionController.serveRequest(LowayTransactionController.java:545)
- at it.loway.tpf.transaction.servlets.LowayTransactionController.serveRequestWrapper(LowayTransactionController.java:387)
- at it.loway.tpf.transaction.servlets.LowayTransactionController.doGet(LowayTransactionController.java:231)
- at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) - at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) - at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
- at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
- at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
- at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
- at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
- at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
- at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
- at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
- at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
- at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
- at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
- at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) - -- End Inner Exception -- - "
```

Comment: I'm not a java person by any means but that looks like you are just missing the jdbc driver for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You should download and add the MySQL JDBC driver under WEB-INF/libs. When runnuning under CentOS what you should really do is:

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d http://yum.loway.ch/loway.repo
yum install queuemetrics
```

That will take care of all details. Also have a look here: https://github.com/Loway/QueueMetricsHowTos/blob/master/QueueMetricsInstall.md

QueueMetrics is really nice to use but it may take some getting started. We have been using it for 5 or 6 years now and are very happy with it.